# SDO_DAS_XML issue for wamp

Tags: php, dll, pecl, sdo

I need for a project to work with SDO_DAS_XML but I am working on windows env. and Wamp and I didn't find any solutions or .dll to make it working.

Is somebody have the two .dll extensions?

I've readed a post here on stackoverflow but the solution given is not really valid. Also PECL4WIN is dead and all links I've found are related to this site.

Any ideas please?